# How do i change a specific line in a textfile

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, streamreader, streamwriter

Im trying to read from a textfile into an array, change one element and then read array back into the file but not appending the original text. But it says the file is being used by another process. Any help is appreciated.

```
        using (StreamReader readName = new StreamReader("fileA"))
        {
            using (StreamReader readColour = new StreamReader("fileB"))
            {

                var lineCount = File.ReadLines("fileB").Count();

                string[] linesA = new string[lineCount];
                string[] linesB = new string[lineCount];

                for (int a = 0; a < linesA.Length; a++)
                {
                    if (linesA[a] == UserVariables.userNameC)
                    {
                        linesB[a] = UserVariables.colourC.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter colourWrite = new StreamWriter("fileB"))
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < linesB.Length; a++)
                    colourWrite.WriteLine(linesB[a], false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would tend to write the file to a memory stream, close the StreamReader to free up the file, then write the stuff from the MemoryStream back to file. Not sure if this is the best way, but have done a few times without any problems!

Comment: You don't even use readName and readColour.

Comment: `readName` and `readColour` don't seem to be used at all? And `linesA` and `linesB` you don't show where you put any data in them...

Comment: for (int a = 0; a < linesA.Length; a++)
                    {
                        linesA[a] = readName.ReadLine();
                        linesB[a] = readColour.ReadLine();
                    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read `fileB` twice,

```
using (StreamReader readColour = new StreamReader("fileB"))  <-- this opens
                                                                 the file 
                                                                 here and
                                                                 leaves it
                                                                 open
{
  var lineCount = File.ReadLines("fileB").Count(); <-- this tries to open it,
                                                       read it and close it.. 
                                                       but it can't because 
                                                       you have it open 
                                                       above..
```

Answer (score 2):

This part opens fileB two times:

```
    using (StreamReader readColour = new StreamReader("fileB"))
    {

        var lineCount = File.ReadLines("fileB").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line `readColour.Close();` in between your read and write sections